# How to look for a value close to a number inside a nested list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have the following list structure:

```
 lista_peliculas = [{'titulo': 'Star Wars: A New Hope', 'estreno' : 1977, 'genero' : 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion' : 121}, 
                           {'titulo': 'Alien', 'estreno' : 1979, 'genero' : 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion' : 117},
                           {'titulo': 'The Next Karate Kid', 'estreno' : 1994, 'genero' : 'Drama', 'duracion' : 107},
                           {'titulo': 'The Terminator', 'estreno' : 1985, 'genero' : 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion' : 107}
        ]
```

And I need to by input get a movie duration (in mintutes) as above, and compare it to the "duracion" value in the dictionary and get the closest value.

For ex input_minutes = input("Enter duration to compare: ")
and i would like to print the number i have stored in the list of dicts that is closest to it along with the rest of the info about that movie. I have no idea how to do it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
lista_peliculas = [{'titulo': 'Star Wars: A New Hope', 'estreno': 1977, 'genero': 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion': 121},
                   {'titulo': 'Alien', 'estreno': 1979, 'genero': 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion': 117},
                   {'titulo': 'The Next Karate Kid', 'estreno': 1994, 'genero': 'Drama', 'duracion': 107},
                   {'titulo': 'The Terminator', 'estreno': 1985, 'genero': 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion': 107}
                   ]

duration_lst = [dictionary['duracion'] for dictionary in lista_peliculas]

duration_inp = int(input("Enter duration"))

closest = duration_lst[min(range(len(duration_lst)), key = lambda i: abs(duration_lst[i]-duration_inp))]

[print(dictionary) for dictionary in lista_peliculas if dictionary['duracion'] == closest]
```

Output:

```
Enter duration>? 115
{'titulo': 'Alien', 'estreno': 1979, 'genero': 'Sci-Fi', 'duracion': 117}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, in order to learn can you explain how you got to this solution, or maybe link to a documentation i shoud read so I can learn more about it?

Comment: Sure...Is it ok if I provide u the explanation after 10 min?

Comment: `min(range(len(duration_lst)), key = lambda i: abs(duration_lst[i]-duration_inp))`  finds the index of the closest element in `durations_lst` by calculating the difference between the `absolute` values of the list elements and the user input. The one with the lowest result is the closest value.

Comment: I can but I can't change it once it's there

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
myNumber = int(input("Enter duration: "))
print(min([x['duracion'] for x in lista_peliculas], key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber)))
```